# r - read.csv - skip rows with different number of columns

Tags: r, csv, null, skip

There are 5 rows at the top of my csv file which serve as information about the file, which I do not need.

These information rows have only 2 columns, while the headers, and rows of data (from 6 on-wards) have 8. **This appears to be the cause of the issue.**

I have tried using the skip function within read.csv to skip these lines, and the same with read.table

```
df = read.csv("myfile.csv", skip=5)
df = read.table("myfile.csv", skip=5)
```

but this still gives me the same error message, which is:

```
Error in read.table("myfile.csv",  :empty beginning of file
```

In addition: Warning messages:

```
1: In readLines(file, skip) : line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
2: In readLines(file, skip) : line 2 appears to contain an embedded nul
...
5: In readLines(file, skip) : line 5 appears to contain an embedded nul
```

How can I get this .csv to be read into r without the null values in the first 5 rows causing this issue?

Comment: There was a file type error. My csv was apparently stored as 'Unicode', even though it said "Microsoft Excel Comma Seper..." under Type in the folder.

Comment: This may be of use for you: the `fread` function that reads a csv file after doing automatic detection of number of rows to be skipped (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332195/reading-in-multiple-csvs-with-different-numbers-of-lines-to-skip-at-start-of-fil/15333597#15333597 )

Answer (score 7):

You could try:

```
read.csv(text=readLines('myfile.csv')[-(1:5)])
```

This will initially store each line in its own vector element, then drop the first five and treat the rest as a csv.

Comment: How can you skip columns if you have some of them causing problems? Here one example http://stackoverflow.com/q/5788117/54964

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of warning messages by using parameter 'skipNul';

```
text=readLines('myfile.csv', skipNul=True)
```

Comment: That only gets rid of the messages, but does not actually solves the problem.